# need output with sub query from the tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

```
FROM THE GIVEN TABLES: Teacher And Student

teacher_ID   name        city           fee   
------------------- ------------------------
1            Jit       New York        15000            
2            Nilon      Paris          13000    
5            Pol        London         11000        
6            Maj        Paris          14000         
7            Paul       Rome           13000
3            Liza       Saudi          12000
----------------------------------------------------------

student_id    name       city         rank        teacher_ID

2         Nick         New York        1               1 
7        Brady         New York        2               1
5        Gunman        California      2               2
8        Juli          London          3               2
4        Faral         Paris           3               6
9        Goku          Berlin          1               3
3        John          Moscow          2               7
1        Badstar       London          5
```

From the Given Tables I need to make a list in ascending order for the students who holds a rank less than 3 and taught either by a teacher or by own.

It's expected output is this

```
name    city       rank      Teacher          city
Nick    New York     1         Jit          New York
John    Moscow       2         Paul         Rome
Gunman California    2         Nilon        Paris
Brady  New York      2         Jit          New York
Goku   Berlin        1         Liza         Saudi
```

I tried writing sql code

```
SELECT name,city,rank FROM Student WHERE rank < 3 ORDER BY student_ID ASC;
```

That code gives me first 3 columns of the expected output however I've no idea how to get the last two column of the expected output, any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Hint: use `left join` with `teacher` table

Comment: be aware rank becomes a reserved word in version 8 you will need to backtick

Comment: I'm using mysql 5.7 in the editor , i'm thinking i need to manipulate teachers_id somehow to change name in the first table as Teacher and display their cities

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You can learn more about `JOIN` here https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

The query...

```
SELECT Student.name,
Student.city,
rank,
Teacher.name as "Teacher",
Teacher.city
FROM Student 
LEFT JOIN Teacher on Teacher.teacher_ID = Student.teacher_ID
WHERE rank < 3 
ORDER BY student_ID ASC;
```

There are a few things that you should consider in the statement

1. When selecting the fields you want to display you need to make sure table column references are unique. As both tables have the field name and city, you should specifically reference them using the format of [table].[column name]
2. There are multiple ways that you can join tables. In this case, you want to use a left join because all data exists in the tables on the left side of the join, and might not exist in the table on the right side of the join.
3. If the student has a result of less than 3 and no teacher, the teacher name and city will appear as null. You might want to consider adding an IFNULL or similar to make these fields clear.

Comment: Thank you , It definitely helped i need to learn more about joining queries